# Focusing an container that has an input below using only CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
}

div:has(input:focus-visible) {
  outline: 2px auto red;
  border: 0;
}

div:has(input:focus-within) {
  border: 1px solid green;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input/>
</div>
```

I have a container with an input inside and some other divs. What I want to achieve is when I focus with the keyboard (using Tab) on the input, the container should be outlined with red, and when I directly click on the container, it should be bordered with green. But in this case only green works.

Comment: Unless you're using something like react, `className` should be `class`

Comment: Focus within applies to the parent div.

Comment: @j08691 fixed it, but the issue is the same

Comment: @Paulie_D so what's the fix then?

Comment: @Paulie_D it works on the child elements as well

Comment: "when I directly click on the container, it should be bordered with green" -- that's not what the CSS targets though. It targets a div with an input that has the focus within it. If you actually want to target the container, you have to make it focusable (by adding `tabindex="0"` to it) and change the selector to `div:focus`. That will give you precisely what you say you want, but not what you likely actually want (which is, I think, have different styling for the container depending on how the input received focus)

Answer (score 1):

You need JavaScript to achieve the second part of your question, you can add a click event listener on the document and check whether the `inputContainer === e.target` in case you want the effect when clicking on the container only or `inputContainer.contains(e.target)` in case you want the effect when clicking on the container or any of its children:

```js
const inputContainer = document.querySelector('.inputContainer');
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (inputContainer === e.target) {
    inputContainer.classList.add('green-border');
  } else {
    inputContainer.classList.remove('green-border');
  }
})
```

```css
.inputContainer {
  padding: 10px;
}

.inputContainer:has(input:focus-visible) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.inputContainer.green-border {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer">

 <input />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Javascript event listeners, stopping the bubbling at the right times:

```js
let input = document.querySelector(".input");
let container = document.querySelector(".container");

input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    this.parentNode.style.border = "2px solid red";
});

input.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

container.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    this.style.border = "1px solid green";
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
    container.style.border = "";
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input class="input" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create the behavior you describe, which is, if you tab to the `input`, the container with have a red outline. If you click the *container*, it will have a green border. If, however, you click the `input`, the container will have the red outline, since the `input` has focus, and the div `:has` it, so the selector matches.

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
}

div:has(input:focus-visible) {
  outline: 2px auto red;
  border: 0;
}

div:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex=0>
  <input/>
</div>
```

Comment: If this was input with the search icon then this method would be bad because firstly the container which does nothing is outlined. But thank you for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

As i can tell, you need to use js here, not only css to detect whether you use tab or a mouse click.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const input = container.querySelector('input');
let focusedViaClick = false;

// Set flag when mousedown event occurs on the input
input.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  focusedViaClick = true;
});

// Clear flag when input loses focus
input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  focusedViaClick = false;
  container.classList.remove('focused', 'clicked');
});

// Add event listener for focus event on the input
input.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  if (focusedViaClick) {
    container.classList.add('clicked');
  } else {
    container.classList.add('focused');
  }
});

// Add event listener for click event on the container
container.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!document.activeElement.matches('input')) {
    container.classList.add('clicked');
  }
});

// Remove class when clicking outside the container
window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (!container.contains(event.target)) {
    container.classList.remove('clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  padding:  1em;
}

#container.focused {
  outline:  2px auto red;
  border:  0;
}

#container.clicked {
  border:  1px solid green;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is the closest, but we need t oactivate focus when we go with tab focus and click again to the input